# How can i delete data from sql tables with foreign key constraints?

Tags: ssms

There is a table TableA where i want to delete data , but i get an error that there is a that
"conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint ....." in Table8.

```
Then when i delete from Table8 it says there is s reference constraint in Table22.

So the issue is that if i try to delete from TableA , there are a number of foreign key constraints.

Is there a way in SSMS so it can construct the delete for me if i give the tables ?
```